# Use of nonetheless in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence

> Though somewhat less coherent than previous chapters and suffering from a minor rash of academic jargon,the final chapter of the book is **nonetheless** **accessible** to laypeople.

what role is played by **nonetheless** here?
If the sentence would have been ..the final chapter of the books is ___ to layperson, then would impenetrable, suffice here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Nonetheless* here is contrasting the accessibility with the difficult academic jargon, in the way one might use "still" or "however". You could also just leave out the *nonetheless* entirely. Its only purpose is to add emphasis to something unexpected - here, the idea that it is unusual to have a chapter with jargon that is accessible to the layperson. You could rewrite the sentence as:

Though somewhat less coherent than previous chapters and suffering from a minor rash of academic jargon,the final chapter of the book is **still** accessible to laypeople.

The final chapter of the book is somewhat less coherent than previous chapters and suffers from a minor rash of academic jargon, **however**, it is accessible to laypeople.

Though somewhat less coherent than previous chapters and suffering from a minor rash of academic jargon,the final chapter of the book is accessible to laypeople.

Answer (score 0):

No, you could not say that the chapter is both *impenetrable* but  *accessible* nonetheless, not unless you were pointing out a paradox.  The ideas yoked by *nonetheless* cannot be *polar* opposites. The ideas have to be going in *roughly opposite* directions, so to speak:

> The chapter uses some big words that most people would find
>   unfamiliar; nonetheless it is well worth the reader's time to
>   look them up, for the chapter contains a wealth of useful information
>   on how to get a panda out of your attic.

"Nonetheless" means "in spite of the aforementioned" or "the aforementioned notwithstanding" or "even so".